# Zurb Foundation Tooltip background opacity issue

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I use Foundation 6 and the tooltip feature.

I tried to add z-index: 9999; and opacity:1 to my tooltip class but without any effect.

```
        <ul class="icons">
          <li >
            <a href="#" class="size thumbnail">XS</a>
          </li>
          <li data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip top" data-disable-hover="t" title="Nicht verfügbar">
            <a href="#" class="size-not thumbnail">S</a>
          </li>
          <li data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip top" data-disable-hover="false" title="Nicht verfügbar">
            <a href="#" class="size-not thumbnail">M</a>
          </li>
          <li class="selected">
            <a href="#" class="size thumbnail">L</a>
          </li>
          <li >
            <a href="#" class="size thumbnail">XL</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

and the belonging css:

```
.has-tip {
  border-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[image]

Everything works as it should except the background text is visible over the tooltip.

[image]

How can i force the tooltip-background to cover the background-text?

Comment: have you tried !important on the css rules?
.has-tip {
  border-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
  opacity: 1;
}

Comment: yeah, but it doesn't have any effect...

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue here..https://jsfiddle.net/4gLb8djb/
Tooltip is over other stuff.. can you update this fiddle so I may help you more!

Comment: Thanks Alegrowin. Strange the tooltip in the jsfiddle doesn't look like the one used in Foundation. i don't know why it looks and behave different then the one i use. i didn't modify anything beside the .has-tip class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've update the JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/4gLb8djb/8/

Just remove the z-index on has.tip element

```
.has-tip {
  border-bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
.tooltip {
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

If it's not working maybe there is an issue with the opacity:
http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: Thanks again Algrowin for your effort. The removing of z-index doesn't have any effect. You can look at https://fadendaten.herokuapp.com/looks to see my tooltip-issue live.

Comment: .tooltip {
  z-index: 10000;
}
currently it is 10